# How to get path and value from XML to excel or CSV?

Tags: xml, excel, csv

I have a task regarding data conversion. I have an XML file that contains the usual things. This is a sample:

```
<parent><child><color>green</color></child></parent>
<otherparent><shuesize>12</shuesize></otherparet>
```

I would like to get this data and import it to excel (or csv) to the following format: Full path of the XML | value.

In the example, this would be a good format:

```
"parent/child/color";"green"
"otherparent/shuesize";"10"
```

What is the most quick and dirty way of doing this? Can Excel do this? Can you recommend some magic script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to list all text elements with its xmlpath.
Excel can't do it, search for a commandline xml parser. Xmlstarlet may be useful for you. (I didn't use it, I have no experience.) If you find a proper tool, select all "//text()" elements and write out their xmlpath and value.